# Does the C++ standard library have a templated getter for the printf conversion specifier?

Tags: c++, std, format-specifiers

As we all know, if for some reason you `printf()` something rather than stream it (which rarely, but sometimes, might happen), you need to specify an appropriate format specifier (`d` for signed int, `u` for unsigned, etc. etc.). Now, since `printf()` is part of the C++ standard library and not just some C legacy, I would hope there might be something like

```
template <typename T> 
const std::string format_specifier;
```

Which would allow, say:

```
template <typename Foo> 
void bar(const Foo& my_foo) {
    printf(format_specifier<Foo>, my_foo);
}
```

Does the standard library contain something like that?

**Notes:**

- Please don't suggest using `std::cout`, of course that's the default thing you should do. I asked about a function that's part of the standard library; if it were removed from it you could say "this should never ever be used, so your question doesn't matter".

Comment: `std::osteam` (like `std::cout`)?

Comment: How about `std::cout` ?

Comment: As far as I know, it does not exist. Your example would have to use `c_str()` on the temporary `std::string` to be compatible with `printf`, by the way.

Comment: @Cornstalks: See edit

Comment: @Shravan40: see edit

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: see edit.

Comment: The short answer is "no", since the C++ standard does not specify any such facilities.   Given properties of functions that are inherited from the C standard library for reasons of backward compatibility (no overloading, permitted in both the global namespace and namespace `std`, etc), and the way that using C++ `iostream` classes is encouraged, I would be surprised if such a feature ever comes to be standardised.

Comment: @Peter: Make that an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @einpoklum why don't you write it yourself? It's so simple.

Comment: How would said `format_specifier` deal with multiple arguments?  Or if the format string is supposed to be `"%d\t%u"`?

Comment: @hroptatyr The \t would not be magically added by the standard if there was such function either. format_specifier<Foo,int,char*, short, long long> can be easily written with variadic templates to output %d%d%c%d%I64d for example, unless you mean something else....

Comment: @Phantom and what's the point of that?  That's the worst possible format string to generate.  I think this whole question is pointless, the point of a format specifier string is to be able to freely specify a format.

Comment: A type-safe C++ printf variadic template function would probably be a better solution -- you could specify any format specifier you want and the function would attempt to convert the argument's value into the desired representation.  Giving a "bad" format would never cause access violations like C's printf.

Answer (score 3):

I originally wrote this as a comment, since it seemed too short.

The short answer is "no", since the C++ standard does not specify any such facilities.

Given properties of functions that are inherited from the C standard library for reasons of backward compatibility (no overloading, permitted in both the global namespace and namespace std, etc), and the way that using C++ `iostream` classes is encouraged, I would be surprised if such a feature ever comes to be standardised.

Answer (score 3):

It does not exist in C++ library for some reasons.

First, if you want C++ to help you to find the correct way to output an object, C++ offers you the injectors on `stream` classes. The stream picks the proper converter and can be twicked through the use of manipulators - it can even be instructed how to print an arbitrary object by overloading `ostream& operator << (ostream&, const T&)`.

But on the other end, the printf format string can used in other languages (Python, Java), and for old programmers that used it a lot can be easier to use than the io manipulators. But it can be used in rather complex strings mixing constant labels and variables on different types :

```
printf("Operation %-*s : %10.2f$ %2d%/02d\n", size, lib, val, dat->mday, dat->mon + 1);
```

I cannot really imagine a way of building easily that string (and it does not use *alternate* variants (`#`))

And as it exists mainly for *compatibility* reasons - after all almost all the C standard library is useable from C++ - I cannot imagine why it would be need further integration.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't but you could code it easily enough, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
char const *format_specifier(); 

template<> inline char const *format_specifier<int>() { return "%d"; }

// ... in function
int d = 5;
printf(format_specifier<decltype(d)>, d);
```

This is pretty gross tho IMHO, and still error-prone. Probably why it is not in the standard library.

A better solution that uses printf-style formatting would be to code:

```
my_printf("bla % bla % bla", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

where `%` just gets the right type from the argument. You can do this using variadic templates and there are some popular implementations of it already.